# How does the 'with' statement work in Flask (Jinja2)?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

In Python you can use the `with` statement like this ([source](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111211102/http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)):

```
class controlled_execution:
    def __enter__(self):
        # set things up
        return thing
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        # tear things down

with controlled_execution() as thing:
     # some code
```

In Flask/Jinja2, the standard procedure for using flash messages is the following ([source](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/flashing/)):

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
  {% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
      <!-- do stuff with `message` -->
    {% endfor %}        
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

I'd like to know how `{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}` works in terms of syntax.

I failed to recreate it in pure Python:

- `with messages = get_flashed_messages(): pass` raises `SyntaxError`
- `with get_flashed_messages() as messages: pass` raises `AttributeError: __exit__`

(I've imported `get_flashed_messages` from `flask` in both cases).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `with` statement in Flask is not the same as the `with` statement in Python.

Within python the equivalent would be this:

```
messages = get_flashed_messages()
```

Comment: Thanks. But how exactly do they differ? Is Flask-with syntactically changed Python-with or something different? Also: I thought that code between `{%` and `%} is 100% Python code.

Comment: They're completely different things, they only share the name but beyond that it's a completely different beast. For the most part everything between `{%` and `%}` is similar to Python, but not completely.

Comment: According to http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/extensions/#with-extension "with" in Jinja2 templates sets up a variable scope. When you close with "with", the variable you define there stops existing. This is like "dtml-with" in a Zope template, not like "with" in a Python context manager.

Answer (score 17):

`{% with %}` statement in Jinja lets you define variable, but limits the scope of a variable with the `{% endwith %}`

statement. For example :

```
{% with myvar=1 %}
...
{% endwith %}
```

Any elements declared in the body will have access to the myvar variable.

Please, refer - https://www.webforefront.com/django/usebuiltinjinjastatements.html

Comment: `with` doesn't work in flask as in django. In flask use `{% set myvar=1 %}`