# Flask.flash messages not available through extended template

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am having trouble with sending flashed messages to a route that extends its layout from another template. This message shows up just fine if use the message in the `layout.html` which makes me believe that rendering `login.html` first will render `layout.html` and use the flashed message there and not pass it to my `/login` route. How are you able to call this message in an extended template? I am using the jijna `with` syntax taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549259/how-does-the-with-statement-work-in-flask-jinja2) to be able to have the message variable available within my mainblock. Flask's [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/patterns/flashing/) does not specify this either.

**app.py**

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    
    # Forget any previous user
    if session.get("user_id"):
        session.pop("user_id")

    if request.method == "POST": 

        # Create connection cursor
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()

        # Query database for email
        cursor.execute("SELECT id, email, password FROM users WHERE email = %s", [request.form.get("email")])
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        print(row)
        if row is None:
            print("WHY")
            flash("Invaid user")
            return redirect("login")
```

My **layout.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Hoook - {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width">
        <link href="/static/favicon-16x16.png" rel="icon">
        <link href="/static/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/542c2d099e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="/static/mainJS.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="page-wrapper">
            <header>
                <nav class="main-navbar">
                {% if request.path == "/login" %}
                    <div class="navbar-container login-container">
                {% else %}
                    <div class="navbar-container">
                {% endif %}
                        <div>
                            {% if request.path == "/login" %}
                                <a href=""><img src="/static/hoook_logo_blue.png" alt="Hoook Logo" height="50" width="150"></a>
                            {% else %}
                                <a href=""><img src="/static/hoook_logo.png" alt="Hoook Logo" height="50" width="150"></a>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                        {% if request.path != "/login" %}
                            <div>
                                {% if session["user_id"] %}
                                    {# change nav bar for logged in users #}
                                {% else %}
                                    {# work on this nav bar for unlogged in users #}
                                    {% if request.path == "/signup" %}
                                        <a class="navbar-link" href="/login">Sign in</a>
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </div>

        <main>
            {% if request.path == "/login" %}
                <div class="top-container signup-container">
            {% else %}
                <div class="top-container">
            {% endif %}
            {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
            {% block main %}{% endblock %}
            {% endwith %}
                </div>
        </main>

        <footer>

        </footer>
    </body>


</html>
```

My **login.html**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Login
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <div class="login-div">
        <div>
            <h1 class="color-control">Sign in to Hoook</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="login-input-bx">
            <form action="/login" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                <div class="form-control login-form-control">
                    <label class="login-label color-control" for="email">Email address</label>
                    <input class="login-input" type="text" name="email" id="email" required autofocus>
                </div>
                <div class="form-control login-form-control">
                    <label class="login-label color-control" for="password">Password</label>
                    <input class="login-input" type="password" name="password" id="password" required readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly')">
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-login" type="submit">Sign in</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        {% if messages %}
            {% for msg in messages %}
                <div class="flashed-messages-div">
                    <p class="signup-para" id="login-flashed-messages">Error: {{ msg }}</p>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        <div class="signup-link-div">
            <p class="color-control signup-login-font">New to Hoook? <a class="signup-link-anchor" href="/signup">Create an account</a>.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**Update**

I guess I could do something like `make_response` instead as seen [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.make_response). and just use:

```
        response = make_response(render_template("login.html", message = "Invalid user"), 302)
        return response
```

However I am curious if there is a way to pass the flashed message through instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue. Instead of:

```
return redirect("login")
```

try with:

```
return render_template("login.html")
```

The flashed message works that way for me.